# Why does ReactDOM.render() render anything but ReactDOM.createRoot().render() does not?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use JSX in React but ReactDOM.createRoot().render() won't render anything:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

ReactDOM.createRoot(root).render(<h1>Hello world</h1>)
```

But when i use ReactDOM.render it works:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello world</h1>, root)
```

It is not like I have a problem with this, but I am more interested why it is this way.

Note: I am using React v17.0.2 and `root` refers to `<div id="root"></div>`.

Comment: which react version are you using?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: And what is `root` in your code?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder <div id="root"></div>

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt: Assuming `root` refers to a DOM element, your first code block is correct for React v18+ but will not work in React v17 or earlier.

Comment: @mohammedabergsson581 - I strongly urge you **not** to rely on automatic DOM globals. Instead, look up the element using `document.getElementById`. (But the automatic DOM global is not the problem here, if that `ReactDOM.render` code works.)

Comment: @NidhinJoseph 17.0.2

Comment: @mohammedabergsson581 - That's the problem. `createRoot` wasn't added until v18. If you look in the devtools console, you should see the error `TypeError: ReactDOM.createRoot is not a function`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Wow, i never really check the versions

Comment: @mohammedabergsson581 - Other people are bound to make the same mistake, so it's useful to have this here. :-) (I searched for a clean previous version of this and couldn't find one.)

Comment: @mohammedabergsson581 - You asked what issues could happen with auto DOM globals. The global namespace is **very** crowded and it's easy for there to be a conflict. `root` (for now) is fine, but if you tried to use an auto DOM global with IDs like `name` or `close` or `event` or any of many others, it would fail with an odd-seeming error. In contrast, those IDs are just fine if you look up the element using `document.getElementById`. There's also the separate issue that it adds clarity to the code, whereas without it, the identifier seems to come out of nowhere to people reading the code. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for solving my problem, i have now upgraded to 18.1.0 and everything is working fine now. I never knew that auto DOM globals could do something like this. I will just stick to document.getElementById() by now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ReactDOM.createRoot` wasn't added until v18. If you look in the devtools console, you should see this error:

> TypeError: ReactDOM.createRoot is not a function

Here's a v17 example showing the error:

```js
const root = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.createRoot(root).render(<h1>Hello world</h1>);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

And a v18 example that works using `createRoot`:

```js
const root = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.createRoot(root).render(<h1>Hello world</h1>);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

For v17, use `ReactDOM.render`. (Or upgrade to v18 and use `createRoot`.)